# how to put a char into a string with a condition

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm very new in informatica and I would like to add a port with a expression which adds a char based on a condition.

example:

ports that are going to be checked:

Input:

a: T

b: T

c: F

output:

Result example: "110"

How I try to resolve it: I added an Expression Transformation

T stands for 1

F stands for 0

```
IIF(a= 'J', result||'1', IIF(b='J', result||'1' , IIF(c='J', result||'1',result||'0')))
```

is this correct? Or is there a better solution, that someone could suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Please use below condition,

```
IIF(a = 'T', '1', IIF(a = 'F', 'O')) ||
IIF(b = 'T', '1', IIF(b = 'F', 'O')) ||
IIF(c = 'T', '1', IIF(c = 'F', 'O'))
```

Not sure why you are concatenating `result`, is it an input/ variable port? If so you can concatenate along with the above function itself as below,

```
IIF(a = 'T', result||'1', IIF(a = 'F', result||'O')) ||
IIF(b = 'T', result||'1', IIF(b = 'F', result||'O')) ||
IIF(c = 'T', result||'1', IIF(c = 'F', result||'O'))
```